# Removing first-level blocks

Tags: regex, replace, pcre

Given some text I want remove all text wrapped between `{` and `}`. The block may themselves contain some block. How can I do that using PCRE regex?

```
\\example input:
{a}b{c{d}}e{f{g}h}

\\output:
be
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [regular expression recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html):

```
\{(?>[^{}]|(?R))*\}
```

See [a regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wS9iH3)

---

PHP example:

```
$input = '{a}b{c{d}}e{f{g}h}';
$output = preg_replace('/\{(?>[^{}]|(?R))*\}/', '', $input);
echo($output); # => be
```

Comment: Remember me ?, You always overtake me !

Comment: @AmitJoki, Post an answer if you have a better solution.

Comment: nah !, was trying to match when your answer came.Have to accept it you are a pretty good regexer

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how regex101 run PCRE regex directly in the browser? It seems it does not communicate with server for server side regex matching.

Comment: @PHPst, I guess it is done in browser. (There's a javascript file like `"/js/pcre16.1385994349.js"` if you see the html page source).